# Encoding 1254 data could not be found make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled

Tags: android, encoding

in the xmarin i have a project and code with c# . with sql server.

it s working in emulator fine and best.
when i am build android and instal a phone it s give me error

Encoding 1254 data could not be found make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled

and not connect sql server.

i am using a vpn

i am not use service

i am directly connect to sql server

in the xmarin i have a project and code with c# . with sql server.

it s working in emulator fine and best.
when i am build android and instal a phone it s give me error

Encoding 1254 data could not be found make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled

and not connect sql server.

how can instal encoding 1254

Comment: C#? [`Encoding.GetEncoding` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding) e.g. `using System;
using System.Text; Encoding e1254 = Encoding.GetEncoding( 1254 );`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].
Moreover, clarify your specific problem or provide additional details
 to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written,
 it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to use UTF-8 on all stack, and try to find which component is using cp1254. You cited a lot of components on your stack, and without knowing which one is using cp1254, we cannot really help. (in any case now world is utf-8, so try to move as much as possible on UTF-8 [which will help debugging this case], and encode/decode to cp1254 only as little as possible (again: it helps debugging). Unicode success was due mainly because that: allowing you to change one layer at a time, without "flags" days.